# Keycloak - direct user link registration

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak

I have set up a web application with Keycloak in my local machine. Since Im using Keycloak as SSO implementation, I want in my web app that whenever **SIGNUP** button is click, user is directed into the registration page, and not going through the **LOGIN** page.

This is the example URL directed to the registration form, however, it contains a `tab_id` that is generated randomly like a session id.

https://site.test/auth/realms/custom/login-actions/authenticate?client_id=test&tab_id=qIdW92Bvwmk

I read about this [link](http://keycloak-user.88327.x6.nabble.com/keycloak-user-Direct-link-to-register-page-td629.html)

> Yes, as long as you use the "registrations" instead of "auth" in the
> end of login ( AuthorizationEndpoint ) URL

But my endpoint in https://site.test/auth/realms/custom/.well-known/openid-configuration cannot be modified.

Comment: did u solve this issue ?

Answer (score 44):

You can change the button link to this format -

```
http://<domain.com>/auth/realms/<realm-name>/protocol/openid-connect/registrations?client_id=<client_id>&response_type=code&scope=openid email&redirect_uri=http://<domain.com>/<redirect-path>&kc_locale=<two-digit-lang-code>
```

Comment: Can you point to the Keycloak documentation where this is mentioned? I am having a hard time finding the URL in the documentations.

Comment: I'm going to guess they referenced this [archived mail-list response](https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2016-August/007473.html).

Comment: For Keycloak v15, `ui_locales` instead of `kc_locale` worked for me to set the language. It's the OIDC standard. Also from the Keycloak docs: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_user_locale_selection

Comment: The `redirect_uri` doesn't work for me, at least not in 15.0.2. As this isn't accepted answer, can somebody confirm it works?

@Sundararajan KS I would appreciate that link

Comment: It works for me with this redirect_uri=http://<domain.com>/<redirect-path> which does not contain any query parameter. We use very complex redirec_uri query parameters for sign in. It does not work with registration. keycloak:16.1.1

Comment: This doesn't work in my 18.0.0 setup. It produces "no state" errors.

Comment: @AscendingEagle I worked around the "no state" error by using a redirect url that points to a page saying "Registration successful. You may login to your new account." The page also display the normal login button that uses the normal login logic. With one click on that button the user is then logged in.

Comment: For me to get the `redirect_uri` working, it had to start with `https://`

Answer (score 1):

The registration page is exposed via an `openid-connect` endpoint, accessible in the same way as the standard auth screen. To construct the correct URL you can simply replace `openid-connect/auth` in the URL with `openid-connect/registrations` from the .well-known auth endpoint.

```js
    authEndpoint.replace("openid-connect/auth","openid-connect/registrations");
```

Using this endpoint the user will be directed to the registration screen instead of the login screen.

It is not documented or exposed via `.well-known/openid-configuration`, but you can see it in the [source code](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/22a16ee899706de77fa21940c6b66fbddb88af0c/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/protocol/oidc/OIDCLoginProtocolService.java#L127):

```java
    public static UriBuilder registrationsUrl(UriBuilder baseUriBuilder) {
        UriBuilder uriBuilder = tokenServiceBaseUrl(baseUriBuilder);
        return uriBuilder.path(OIDCLoginProtocolService.class, "registrations");
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What is "replace"? How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

For Keycloak 17 this worked for me:

http://<mykeycloakdomain.com>/realms//protocol/openid-connect/registrations?client_id=<myclient_id>&response_type=code&scope=openid+email&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmywebsiteurl.com&kc_locale=

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Igor please explain with details in your answer to make it more useful for other users !

Comment: This gives a 404 error.