# Send password forgotten mail

Tags: keycloak

I have two similar use cases in Keycloak.

**Password reset**

First is, I want to enable users to reset their passwords. There is already an application the users are using, so it would be nice to integrate it there. I created a small anngular module within it and tried to trigger a password forgotten mail via the same mechanism the Keycloak password forgotten form provides. But I can't figure out how they created this action link:

> https://example.com/keycloak/auth/realms/my-realm/login-actions/reset-credentials?session_code=dpmvJISKKf-SSZbC8_FkrBZEuYhwcV24ui-dc27DKvI&execution=98bd5b5d-054e-4c44-ad07-50b668fb149a&client_id=account&tab_id=Lr7iH6BRehM

The execution seems to be always the same, but I have no clue where to get it in the first place.

My current solution, which works while Keycloak and the application run on the sam domain, is to request the original site from keycloak, extract the link and after the user enters the username make a post request to that URL. But that is a little bit dirty :)

Is there a "correct" way to do that?

**Addition to password reset**

We have different realms to work with user accounts that are in LDAP with a SASL attribute and the real password stored in MSAD. Our frontend figures out which type of user is requesting the password reset and delegates to the appropriate realm.

**Initial Password**

The second question is about creating users in an admin area and send an initial mail to set a password. I could use the method from above to trigger a mail. But it not good that the mail says password forgotten while they realy have to set the password for the first time.
I tried to set required actions in the users REST representation, but it seems that this triggers no mail.

Are required actions to intened way to do that? Did I miss a feature?

**Addition to password reset**
We have different realms to work with user accounts that are in LDAP with a SASL attribute and the real password stored in MSAD. Our frontend figures out which type of user is requesting the password reset and delegates to the appropriate realm.

Answer (score 4):

There are quite a lot of admin-api endpoints that are provided by keycloak [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/9.0/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource)

For your requirements;

1. Password reset - You should be able to do this by leveraging the API "PUT /{realm}/users/{id}/execute-actions-email". There are a bunch of examples in StackOverflow including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55041506/how-to-execute-actions-email-in-keycloak)
2. Initial Password - For creating users, you should be able to use a similar approach when calling "POST /{realm}/users" since you are able to pass the "required actions" in the [UserRepresentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/9.0/rest-api/index.html#_userrepresentation) object. Also, you may combine this API with the previous API to satisfy your need. There are other APIs here that you could use however, remember that keycloak also gives a [registration page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51514437/keycloak-direct-user-link-registration) as well for users. 
   Please do check out the "PUT /{realm}/users/{id}/reset-password" as well.

Check this link for an [explanation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#required-actions) of required-actions.

Note that in order to call keycloak admin-api you should create a client that has sufficient privileges to call admin-api. The configuration for this will depend on the authorization mechanism you are planning to use - but to get a gist of it - create a client and check the alternatives available on the client page - attaching a screenshot for your reference;

[image: client-screen-snap]

Good luck!

Comment: 1) The users should reset their password on their own, so the admin API doesn't work here.
2) Required actions seems to be the wrong way. From the link you quoted: "..a user must finish before they are allowed to log in. A user must provide their credentials before required actions are executed.". He can't provide his credentials, because he doesn't have them yet.
I just want an admin to create a user and then send the user an email, so that he can set his credentials

Comment: Turns out, while required action doesn't work for an initial password in my configuration, execute-actions-email did work. So I'm currently left with the problem to let users reset their password on their own.